# Oracle : how to subtract two dates and get minutes of the result

Tags: oracle, date, plsql

I wrote this function to get minutes from a date, but I cannot get minutes between two dates, How to get that ?

```
FUNCTION get_minute(p_date DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
    IF p_date IS NOT NULL THEN
        return  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char(p_date,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
    ELSE
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;
END get_minute;
```

Comment: `to_char(p_date, 'MI')` would work for minute extraction

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle - Best SELECT statement for getting the difference in minutes between two DateTime columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206222/oracle-best-select-statement-for-getting-the-difference-in-minutes-between-two)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

When you subtract two dates in Oracle, you get the *number of days between the two values*. So you just have to multiply to get the result in minutes instead:

```
SELECT (date2 - date1) * 24 * 60 AS minutesBetween
FROM ...
```

Comment: My problem with this is that the resulting object (`minutesBetween`) is duration of as many _days_ as the minutes between date2 and date1. How do I get a simple number? I cannot convert that `to_number(...)`, I think. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a `Round` function too.

Answer (score 16):

For those who want to substrat two timestamps (instead of dates), there is a similar solution:

```
SELECT ( CAST( date2 AS DATE ) - CAST( date1 AS DATE ) ) * 1440 AS minutesInBetween
FROM ...
```

or

```
SELECT ( CAST( date2 AS DATE ) - CAST( date1 AS DATE ) ) * 86400 AS secondsInBetween
FROM ...
```

Comment: I recommend this answer cause it doesn't depend on the date format stored in the database.
Get elapsed minutes: 
SELECT (SYSDATE- CAST( date_column AS DATE ) )* 1440  FROM my_table

Answer (score 1):

I think you can adapt the function to substract the two timestamps:

```
return  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM 
  TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char(p_date1,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
-
  TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char(p_date2,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
);
```

I think you could simplify it by just using `CAST(p_date as TIMESTAMP)`.

```
return  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM cast(p_date1 as TIMESTAMP) - cast(p_date2 as TIMESTAMP));
```

Remember dates and timestamps are big ugly numbers inside Oracle, not what we see in the screen; we don't need to tell him how to read them.
Also remember timestamps can have a timezone defined; not in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I can handle this way:

```
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'MI')) - to_number(to_char(*YOUR_DATA_VALUE*,'MI')),max(exp_time)  from ...
```

Or 
if you want to the hour just change the MI;

```
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')) - to_number(to_char(*YOUR_DATA_VALUE*,'HH24')),max(exp_time)  from ...
```

the others don't work for me. 
Good luck.