# Generate a table with a range of timestamps - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to create a table with 2 columns in the below format with all the dates of 2019:-

```
      START_TIME          END_TIME
2010-01-01 17:00:00|2019-01-02 17:00:00
2019-01-02 17:00:00|2019-01-03 17:00:00
2019-01-03 17:00:00|2019-01-04 17:00:00
...
...
2019-12-31 17:00:00|2020-01-01 17:00:00
```

Could you please help troubleshoot the error in this?
Please suggest any optimized way of achieving this.

```
CREATE TABLE s.dates_2019
(
ts_range_begin timestamp(6),
ts_range_end timestamp(6),

);


 insert into s.dates_2019 (ts_range_begin)
 select 
     to_timestamp('12/31/2018 05:00 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + n.n
 from
  (select rownum n
   from   ( select 1 just_a_column
         from   dual
         connect by level <=
                to_timestamp('12/31/2019 05:00 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
               -  to_timestamp('12/31/2018 05:00 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  
               + 1
           ) t
  ) n
  where
       to_timestamp('12/31/2018 05:00 PM','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  + n.n <=  to_timestamp('12/31/2019 05:00 PM','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 

 insert into s.dates_2019 (ts_range_end)
 select 
     to_timestamp('2019-01-01 05:00 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') + n.n
 from
  (select rownum n
   from   ( select 1 just_a_column
         from   dual
         connect by level <=
                to_timestamp('2020-01-01 05:00 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
               -  to_timestamp('2019-01-01 05:00 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  
               + 1
           ) t
  ) n
  where
       to_timestamp('2019-01-01 05:00 PM','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')  + n.n <=  to_timestamp('2020-01-01 05:00 PM','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Error is :-
`[Error Code: 30081, SQL State: 99999]  ORA-30081: invalid data type for datetime/interval arithmetic`

Comment: The format `to_timestamp('12/31/2018 05:00 PM', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` is wrong. String `12/31/2018 05:00 PM` is not as of `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`, they have to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi';

Session altered.

SQL> with dates as
  2    (select date '2019-01-01' + 17/24 + level - 1 datum
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= date '2020-01-01' - date '2019-01-01' + 1
  5    ),
  6  staend as
  7    (select datum as start_time,
  8            lead(datum) over (order by datum) as end_time
  9     from dates
 10    )
 11  select start_time,
 12         end_time
 13  from staend
 14  where end_time is not null
 15  order by start_time;

START_TIME       END_TIME
---------------- ----------------
2019-01-01 17:00 2019-01-02 17:00
2019-01-02 17:00 2019-01-03 17:00
2019-01-03 17:00 2019-01-04 17:00
2019-01-04 17:00 2019-01-05 17:00
<snip>
2019-12-30 17:00 2019-12-31 17:00
2019-12-31 17:00 2020-01-01 17:00

365 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to insert dates into a table, you don't really need a `timestamp` - `date` will do.

```
SQL> create table dates_2019
  2    (ts_range_begin date,
  3     ts_range_end   date
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into dates_2019 (ts_range_begin, ts_range_end)
  2  with dates as
  3    (select date '2019-01-01' + 17/24 + level - 1 datum
  4     from dual
  5     connect by level <= date '2020-01-01' - date '2019-01-01' + 1
  6    ),
  7  staend as
  8    (select datum as start_time,
  9            lead(datum) over (order by datum) as end_time
 10     from dates
 11    )
 12  select start_time,
 13         end_time
 14  from staend
 15  where end_time is not null
 16  order by start_time;

365 rows created.

SQL>
```

---

If you want to aggregate weekends, consider using **offset** in the `lead` analytic function. That offset depends on day name (Friday). Also, remove weekend days from the result set (line #21, `where day not in ('sat', 'sun')`).

```
SQL> insert into dates_2019 (ts_range_begin, ts_range_end)
  2  with dates as
  3    (select date '2019-01-01' + 17/24 + level - 1 datum,
  4            --
  5            to_char(date '2019-01-01' + 17/24 + level - 1,
  6                    'fmdy', 'nls_date_language = english') day
  7     from dual
  8     connect by level <= date '2020-01-01' - date '2019-01-01' + 1
  9    ),
 10  staend as
 11    (select datum as start_time,
 12            day,
 13            lead(datum, case when day = 'fri' then 3
 14                             else 1
 15                        end) over (order by datum) as end_time
 16     from dates
 17    )
 18  select start_time,
 19         end_time
 20  from staend
 21  where day not in ('sat', 'sun')
 22    and end_time is not null;

261 rows created.

SQL> select * from dates_2019 order by ts_range_begin;

TS_RANGE_BEGIN   TS_RANGE_END
---------------- ----------------
2019-01-01 17:00 2019-01-02 17:00
2019-01-02 17:00 2019-01-03 17:00
2019-01-03 17:00 2019-01-04 17:00
2019-01-04 17:00 2019-01-07 17:00     --> aggregated
2019-01-07 17:00 2019-01-08 17:00
2019-01-08 17:00 2019-01-09 17:00
2019-01-09 17:00 2019-01-10 17:00
2019-01-10 17:00 2019-01-11 17:00
2019-01-11 17:00 2019-01-14 17:00     --> aggregated
2019-01-14 17:00 2019-01-15 17:00
2019-01-15 17:00 2019-01-16 17:00
<snip>
```

Comment: Thank you..is there a function i can use to aggregate the weekend date (Friday to Monday)   like below:- `                                                                                                       
 START_TIME       END_TIME
---------------- ----------------
2019-01-01 17:00 2019-01-02 17:00
2019-01-02 17:00 2019-01-03 17:00
2019-01-03 17:00 2019-01-04 17:00
2019-01-04 17:00 2019-01-07 17:00 `

Comment: You're welcome. I added some more code which aggregates weekends. Have a look, please.

Comment: Thank you so much..this entirely solves my use case.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think your actual error is because subtracting timestamps returns an interval, whereas you're using the result as a number in `CONNECT BY LEVEL`. You could cast the timestamps as dates (you might find [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408819/oracle-how-to-subtract-two-dates-and-get-minutes-of-the-result/44587338) useful) or use an [interval expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/expressions009.htm#SQLRF52064) to get the day component between the timestamps.

But if this is your actual SQL and not a simplification, I suggest just using dates in the `CONNECT BY` (you can still keep timestamps in your table if that's what you want) and doing something like...

```
CREATE TABLE dates_2019
(
ts_range_begin timestamp(6),
ts_range_end timestamp(6)
);

insert into dates_2019 (ts_range_begin)
 select 
     to_timestamp('2018-12-31 17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') + rownum
 from
     dual
 connect by level <= to_date('2019-12-31 17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') - to_date('2018-12-31 17', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24')
 ;

update dates_2019 SET ts_range_end = ts_range_begin + 1;
```

... which I tested in Oracle 18c, but probably works 10g.