# Substract two different timestamps and convert into mins in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the below query in SQL Server to subtract two different dates and convert the difference as minutes.

- BADGE_OUT_TIME = 2021-05-26 13:33:14.000
- BADGE_IN_TIME =  2021-05-26 13:30:24.000
- WORKING_HOURS = 3

The below select query will give 3 (mins) as result.

1. **SQL Server**

```
    SELECT 
    ISNULL(DATEDIFF(minute, s.BADGE_IN_TIME,s.BADGE_OUT_TIME),0) AS WORKING_HOURS FROM ATTENDANCE
```

I am trying to write the query in Oracle like below but it is not working. Kindly help

1. **Oracle query**

```
    SELECT COALESCE(TO_DATE(BADGE_OUT_TIME ) - TO_DATE(BADGE_IN_TIME),0) AS WORKING_HOURS FROM ATTENDANCE
```

Comment: It seems that you are also rounding the result to 3 minutes. Is that correct? Also, if the result is 3 minutes, why is it called "working **hours**"? Are you sure you shouldn't change that name?

Comment: Oracle's date difference returns number of days between two dates. You need to multiply it by 60*24

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle : how to subtract two dates and get minutes of the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408819/oracle-how-to-subtract-two-dates-and-get-minutes-of-the-result)

Answer (score 1):

Let try this query

```
SELECT ROUND(((BADGE_OUT_TIME - BADGE_IN_TIME )*24*60*60/60),2) AS PROCESS_TIME_IN_MINS
FROM ATTENDANCE
```